# addAll() method from ArrayList <E> class does not work

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am struggling with understanding why the addAll() method from ArrayList does not work.
I have my class:

```
public class XList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {...

}
```

With a method:

```
public XList<E> union(XList<E> input) {
    System.out.println(this);//
    System.out.println(input);
    this.addAll(input);
    return this;
}
```

System.out.println indicates, that correct values are in the given lists, but after adding, "this" does not get updated, and is returned without modification.
Could you please clue me in, on the root of the problem?
Any help greatly appreciated.

SSCCE:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    XList<Integer> list1 = new XList<>(1, 3, 9, 11);
    XList<Integer> list2 = XList.of(5, 6, 9);


    List<Integer> m1 = list1.union(list2);
    System.out.println(m1);

}

}

class XList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

private List<E> lista;

public XList(E a, E b, E c) {
    lista = new ArrayList<>();
    lista.add(a);
    lista.add(b);
    lista.add(c);
}

public XList(E a, E b, E c, E d) {
    lista = new ArrayList<>();
    lista.add(a);
    lista.add(b);
    lista.add(c);
    lista.add(d);

}

static XList of(Integer a, Integer b, Integer c) {

    return new XList(a, b, c);
}

public XList<E> union(XList<E> input) {

    System.out.println("this: " + this);
    System.out.println("input: " + input);
    this.addAll(input);
    return this;
}


public String toString() {

    return lista.toString();
}
```

Comment: does `this.addAll(input);` return `true` ?

Comment: Just checked, and it does not...

Comment: To get better help provide [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)) - in short code example which we could copy-paste to our machines and without any modifications run and reproduce problem you are getting. This way we can use proper tools like debugger to locate source of the problem easier.

Comment: *This way we can use proper tools like debugger* - suggest OP uses the proper tools too

Comment: Why do you have `private List<E> lista;` if you already `extends ArrayList<E>`? This way you have two lists, one under `lista` and one under `this` which are *separate* objects.

Comment: Probably the best way to do what you want to do is to have `XList` not extend `ArrayList` but instead to have it extend `AbstractList`. Then override the get, size, set, add, and remove methods and have them delegate to the contained ArrayList.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that your XList confusingly both extends ArrayList and also contains a list as a field. That means that XList basically is two separate lists: it's a list itself and it also includes a different separate list

If I were you I'd remove "extends ArrayList" and replace

```
this.addAll(input);
```

With

```
this.lista.addAll(input.lista);
```

Comment: What inherited methods, do you mean equals, hashCode, toString? Overriding those is optional. Maybe you skipped over the phrase *remove "extends ArrayList"*?

Comment: I indeed overlooked that you already suggested to remove `extends ArrayList`.